# Bash Sorting STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to write a bash script that sorts the input by rules in different files. The first rule is to write all chars or strings in file1. The second rule is to write all numbers in file2. The third rule is to write all alphanumerical strings in file3. All specials chars must be ignored. Because I am not familiar with bash I don t know how to realize this.

Could someone help me?

Thanks,
Haniball

Thanks for the answers,

I wrote this script,

```
#!/bin/bash

inp=0 echo "Which filename for strings?" 
read strg 
touch $strg
echo "Which filename for nums?"
read nums
touch $nums
echo "Which filename for alphanumerics?"
read alphanums
touch $alphanums
while [ "$inp" != "quit" ]
do
 echo "Input: "
 read inp
 echo $inp | grep -o '\<[a-zA-Z]+>' > $strg
 echo $inp | grep -o '\<[0-9]>' > $nums
 echo $inp | grep -o -E '\<[0-9]{2,}>' > $nums
done
```

After I ran it, it only writes string in the stringfile.

Greetings, Haniball

Comment: Does this actually need to be written in `bash(1)`? Significantly more convenient tools exist for manipulating text. Also, I'm pretty unclear on what you're trying to accomplish -- you'll need to give an input file and output files before anyone will understand what you're trying to do. And last, Stack Overflow is for _questions_ and _answers_ -- it is NOT a _please do my work for me_ site. You'd do better to show us your attempt at solving the problem, and ask for help with something specific with it.

Comment: Show us your input, without it, there is not much we can do...

Comment: input is: '42' then 'quit'. after that it only puts 'quit' into stringfile. The file for numerics is empty.

Comment: change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output. Think you mean `>>` for the grep lines above, i.e. append, else files will be overwritten with nothing if no match

Comment: thanks Fredrik. >> did the trick. Of course, I just had to append not overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is sufficient (your question is a bit vague. If I got something wrong, let me know...)

Using the following input file:

> this is a string containing words,
>   single digits as in 1 and 2 as well
>   as whole numbers 42 1066

**all chars or strings**

```
$ grep -o '\<[a-zA-Z]\+\>' sorting_input
this
is
a
string
containing
words
single
digits
as
in
and
as
well
```

**all single digit numbers**

```
$ grep -o '\<[0-9]\>' sorting_input
1
2
```

**all multiple digit numbers**

```
$ grep -o -E '\<[0-9]{2,}\>' sorting_input
42
1066
```

Redirect the output to a file, i.e. `grep ... > file1`

Answer (score 2):

Sure can help. See here:

- [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [Help Vampires: A Spotter’s Guide](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- cool site about the bash is here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php
- for sorting try `man sort`
- for pattern matching try `man grep`
- other useful tools: `man sed` `man awk` `man strings` `man tee`

And it is always correct tag your homework as "homework" ;)

You can try something like:

```
<input_file strings -1 -a | tee chars_and_strings.txt |\
grep "^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$" | tee alphanum.txt |\
grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" > numonly.txt
```

The above is only for USA - no international (read unicode) chars, where things coming a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Bash really isn't the best language for this kind of task. While possible, ild highly recommend the use of perl, python, or tcl for this.

That said, you can write all of stdin from input to a temporary file with shell redirection. Then, use a command like grep to output matches to another file. It might look something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > temp

grep pattern1 > file1
grep pattern2 > file2
grep pattern3 > file3

rm -f temp
```

Then run it like this:

```
cat file_to_process | ./script.sh
```

I'll leave the specifics of the pattern matching to you.